# Regex matching exact pattern (full word with or without apostrophe) and not partial components of a word

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to match full words with or without an apostrophe.

I did this:

```
\b[a-zA-Z']+\b
```

However, it is matching the letters in bold **J**ö**nas** while the desired is to not match the word Jönas at all because of the **ö** on it.

The right matches should go for anything in **a-zA-Z'**

Thus following cases should match in full:

```
Jonas
Don't
hasn'T
```

But not for:

```
Jönas
Dön't
Hélló
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/1/ (where Jönas and Hélton should not be matched at all not even partially)

How to fix the regex, to follow this exact match?

Comment: Enable unicode mode to make it work: https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE.** Anubhava and Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out that using `\b[a-zA-Z']+\b` in Unicode mode is enough ([fiddle 1](https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/2) and [fiddle 2](https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/5)).

As said Wiktor, there is no use case the answer below is relevant (no engine supports look-around groups while not supporting Unicode mode). **So this answer isn't anymore relevant.**

---

You can use this regex:

```
\b(?<![\x80-\xFF])[a-zA-Z']+(?![\x80-\xFF])\b
```

Here, `[\x80-\xFF]` stands for a range of character codes above ASCII 7bit set (where non-english letters lies). Basically, it looks for:

- a sequence of english letters with or without apostrophes ...
- not preceded by non-english letters (negative look-before group `(?<!...)`
- not followed by non-english letters (negative look-ahead group `(?!...)`

[Working Regex101.com sample](https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/4).

Comment: `\b[a-zA-Z']+\b` is enough. See this https://regex101.com/r/2sVN5S/5 demo.

Comment: Yes, and that is why it is enough.

Comment: @Amessihel Only in JavaScript. But yours is not a solution then.

Comment: `sed` does not support lookarounds.