# Wordpress PHP Search complete words not a part of it and replace

Tags: php, wordpress, replace

*The answers I have found did unfortunately not point me into the right direction, therefore I'd like to open my own thread.*

**I have to replace the term "MEN" with "männer", but not when partly appearing in "WOMEN" or it results in "WOmänner".**

And I have to keep using case insensitive str_ireplace.

Thank you for your kind help.

```
add_filter( 'wpla_filter_listing_feed_column', 'amazon_change_text_EU', 10, 3 );
    function amazon_change_text_EU( $value, $col, $item ) {
    
    // RULES FOR ALL MARKETPLACES
            $allowed = array( 'US','CA');
            $market_code = WPLA()->accounts[ $item['account_id'] ]->market_code;
            if ( in_array( $market_code, $allowed ) ) return $value;
    
    
             // TRANSLATE BULLET POINTS
            if ( $col == 'product_description') {
                $replaceThis = Array(
    
      
                'Men'     => 'Männer',
               
            );
    
                 $value = str_ireplace(array_keys($replaceThis), $replaceThis, $value);
            return $value;
            }
   return $value;
    }
```

I tried to adopt this solution bellow, but it either throws errors or does not replace the words:

```
add_filter("wpla_filter_listing_feed_column", "amazon_change_text_EU", 10, 3);
function amazon_change_text_EU($value, $col, $item)
{
    // RULES FOR ALL MARKETPLACES
    $allowed = ["US", "CA"];
    $market_code = WPLA()->accounts[$item["account_id"]]->market_code;
    if (in_array($market_code, $allowed)) {
        return $value;
    }

    // TRANSLATE BULLET POINTS
    if ($col == "product_description") {
        $replaceThis = [
            ' Men\'s' => " Männer",
            ' Children\'s' => " Kinder",
            ' Women\'s' => " Frauen",
        ];

        $value = preg_replace_callback(
            "/\w+/", # only match whole words
            function ($m) use ($replaceThis) {
                if (isset($replaceThis[$m[0]])) {
                    //strtolower
                    return $preplaceThis[$m[0]];
                } else {
                    return $m[0]; # keep unreplaced
                }
            },
            $value
        );
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: If the way mentioned in the duplicate is not working for you, then you need to properly explain to us, _how_ it isn't working. That starts with showing us how you actually tried to use it.

Comment: _"but it either throws errors"_ - that is a very useless thing to say. If you are getting errors, then quote the error message verbatim, please. (Plus whatever actual example data we would need, to reproduce.) _"or does not replace the words"_ - it works fine, if the array keys are matched case-sensitive. If you want case-insensitive matching - then `# optional: strtolower` actually isn't optional, and you need to apply that to the found match first.

Comment: And regarding that latest edit - you are storing the string with the matches replaced in `$r`, but then your function still returns the unchanged `$value` at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I am not an experienced php developer and try as good as I can. Updated the code to the actual example I tested. It does not throw and error, but does also not replace the text. Furthermore, I would need to be able to replace a whole sentence and single words. Like "Men's" to "Männer" or *This Mens T-shirt" to "Dieses Männer T-Shirt". Not sure if that does work as one single function without running into issues.

Comment: `\w+` will not match `Men's`, but only the `Men` part - because `'` is not a word character.

Comment: This is why I was trying to post a "new" topic, as my situation is different than the one in the link given. Thank you

Comment: Well then do a bit more _research_, please! "php regex match full words including apostrophe" typed into Google, led me to https://stackoverflow.com/q/64581012/1427878 quickly.

Comment: _"This is why I was trying to post a "new" topic, as my situation is different than the one in the link given"_ - your question, _this_ question here, did not even contain any mention that you need it to work for `Men's` as well, at the time the duplicate was suggested.

Comment: Thank you. Again, I am a Graphics Designer and just trying to solve a "small" issue and most of the code and language is difficult for me. I also support users in 3D and what is logical to me, is not for others and then I am happy to help if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257160/discussion-between-gto-and-cbroe).